# How I prevent having too much parameters in a function. C++

Tags: c++, function, opengl, parameters, arguments

I am making a game engine with C++ and Opengl. I making a small game to test my incomplete engine. But after adding classes like Camera, Renderder, Level, Player, Zombie and Human, My Player class's function parameters getting long about 8 arguments because player needs to interact with many classes like Camera, Renderder, Zombie, Human, etc.

Please give suggestions to solve this problem
Or this is the right way to make games.

Comment: I wouldn't call that too much. Complicated things are complicated. With that said, there's only ever one camera, I imagine. Does a Player need a Zombie incorporated into it? There's no real information to go off of.

Comment: Could all these objects be in a `struct` that you can pass by reference?

Comment: You question is to broad. Generally this is where software engineering and architecture comes into play: Why is your player class the intgrator of everything? Shouldn't your engine look how the classes interact? Also yes that engine would have to integrate much stuff, but for many things that behaves alike, like Zombies and Humans, Abstraction in the form of interfaces and object polymorphism or even templates/generic programming comes to mind. And yes you can also just bundle stuff together in a struct. But that probably won't help the original problem.

Comment: Why does the constructor need the Zombie part? In any case, consider splitting big classes. Have a class for appearance and one for game logic, for instance. Highly depends on the context.

Comment: A function that needs camera, renderer _and_ zombies and humans looks like a function that can be split up. For example you could split it in a render function that only need Camera and renderer and an update function that needs the zombies and humans (maybe, don't know your design). I would just have an engine class that is passed by reference and contains all the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say without more context. However, one extreme is to bundle everything needed as parameter into a single struct:

```
 struct GameContext {
      Camera camera;
      Renderer renderer;
      Level level;
      Player player;
      //...
 };
```

and then pass that as single parameter:

```
 void foo(const GameContext& context);
```

However, whether this is feasible depends not only on the function that you want to pass that structure as parameter. Rather you have to consider more than that to decide what belongs together and what not. Sometimes the other extreme (passing 8 individual parameters) can be the right thing. If that function is the only place where those 8 parameters appear together, then you would not put them in a struct merely to call that one function.

To summarize, I think you are trying to fix something at the wrong abstraction level. Consider the whole architecture and how your objects are supposed to interact with each other. A `Camera` or a `Renderer` is not something I would expect to be passed around that often. You need to tell a `Player` only once what `Camera` they should use (if at all) not every time you call one of `Player`s methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, objects that are single inside a scene, can be implemented via singleton pattern, then you would be able to access them from any class simply by adding a required header.

Second, some of the objects can be represented as parents for others - like Legs or Hands for Human, make use of composition.

Third, as most interactions between objects (like collisions and stuff) are common between all objects, you can leave most of the implementation in the base class, which would free *Zombies* from accessing Camera at all, because *Object* already does that. Make use of inheritance!

Fourth, if nothing worked, you can group up them all within a struct of pointers to these objects, and pass a single struct instead of N parameters.

Pretty much that.

Comment: Singletons used like that have some of the problems that make global variables evil. Like initializing order. Now I don't rule them completely out, but I'd say one should think quite hard if one wants to use one in a given situation. (I agree with your other points.)

Comment: Initialization can be postponed via some init(...) methods or something like that. Of course, using singletons right does require discipline.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer with without seeing some of the code, but here are some thoughts:

- just because your player needs to interact with many classes doesn't mean they all have to appear in the same function call. In fact, if "camera" and "zombie" appear in the same function call, I suspect your functions are not very clear in their purpose. Each function should ideally do one thing, and get only the parameters it needs.
- if you don't have that already, try to find appropriate base classes - e.g., your player class might interact with an instance of a Monster class, which might either be a Zombie, or a Vampire, or a Werewolf.
- if you still find your parameter lists to be too long to handle, find objects that live on the same level of abstraction, or in the same domain, and put them together into aggregate objects that you hand into your functions. For example, camera and renderer could go into "viewer", whereas  monsters, non-player characters, and items could be contained in a "level" or a "world".