# How to avoid too many arguments in a function. C++

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, game-engine

I am making a small game in my small game engine made with OpenGL c++.
I have to make many classes like Camera, BatchRenderer, AudioEngine, ParticleEngine, Level, Player, Zombie, Humans, etc. Now Player have to interact with classes like Camera, BatchRenderer, AudioEngine, ParticleEngine, level data from Level class, Zombie, Human, etc. And i am passing most of them by reference which are initialized in my Main Game class.

// AudioEngine and ParticleEngine which is created in Main Game class and Player need to play sound and simulate particles. TextureID, position, radius(size), rotation, depth and color are needed to render the player.

```
Player::Player(AudioEngine& a_audioEngine, ParticleEngine& a_particleEngine
               GLuint a_textureID, glm::vec2 a_position, float a_radius,
               float a_rotation, float a_depth, Color a_color)
{...}
```

// Camera for checking if the player is in view. levelData, zombies, humans to check collision detection with Player.

```
void Player::update(Camera& camera, std::vector<std::string>& levelData,
                    std::vector<Zombie>& zombies, std::vector<Human>& humans,
                    float deltaTime)
```

Here you can see too many arguments are passed to player class and also need more in the future.
But I read many people saying the it is bad to have more than two or three arguments in a function. And In my game there are many classes which take more than 5 or 6 arguments.

Is this right for a game Or Is it is a bad practice?
Please tell me how can i solve this problem.

Sorry for bad English.
Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: Maybe you could have a `Game` class that contains all the pertinent objects for the current game instance? It might be that things can be re-designed to reduce the number of needed parameters. It is hard to be specific without more details.

Comment: You may read about the mediator pattern. This could help.

Comment: you asked the same question before. If a quesiton gets closed you can edit it, it will then be reviewed and if the issues are fixed eventually be reopened (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61390127/4117728)

Comment: Sorry but some people are telling that the question was incomplete, and lack in information. And I thought that updating the question will not work.

Comment: You're weighing down your player with too many responsibilities. Leave "system things" like audio, rendering, collisions, game rules, and so on outside the player, and let those systems be aware of the player (and other things) and react to what it's doing.

Comment: If I have separate bullets(vector of bullet class) for player, zombies and human, I have to write different functions for checking collision for different classes in my main system class and this will make the class very big.

Comment: updating the question does work. There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61390127/edit) link below the question. Also the close banner told you "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question." (including the same link)

Answer (score 1):

Having too many argument is bad only if you call your function a lot of time in your program as you pay the cost of putting the parameter of your function on the stack plus the indirection of the function call.

If you are not calling those functions a lot of time then don't bother packing the variables.

If you need the pack the variable, you can just put them into a `struct` and pass a single argument to the function (usually a reference to avoid the copy)!

Answer (score 0):

Having too many arguments in function is bad, but it is not scalable and clean. It cause user of function inconvenient and for you it would be hard to maintain also. You can not add or delete parameter in function it would take lots of time to do that. One more thing you don't need to make too long struct also. If struct become too long split into meaningful structs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really concerned about it you can pass arguments in a struct. It's no less efficient as far as the compiler is concerned.

If you have c++17, you can unpack the struct with a structured binding for readability.

If you have c++20 you can create the struct with named initialisation.

e.g:

```
#include <string>

struct vec {
    double x, y, z;
};

struct func_args {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    double c;
    vec x , y , z;
};

void foo(std::string const&, vec const&);

void func(func_args const& args) {
    // c++17 feature - structured binding (in this case by reference)
    auto& [a, b, c, x, y, z] = args;
    foo(b, x);
}

// or by value...
void func(func_args&& args) {
    auto [a, b, c, x, y, z] = std::move(args);
    foo(b, x);
}

void test()
{
    // c++20 feature (and gcc extension prior). Named initialisation.
    func({ .a = 0, .b = "alien", .c = 0.0, 
        .x = { -1, 1, 0}, 
        .y = { -1, 1, 0}, 
        .z = { -1, 1, 0}});

    auto const args2 = func_args { 
        .a = 0, .b = "alien", .c = 0.0, 
        .x = { -1, 1, 0}, 
        .y = { -1, 1, 0}, 
        .z = { -1, 1, 0}};
    func(args2);
}
```

C++ looks more like javascript every year :)

Comment: It's even more fun to write: `.x{.x{-1},.y{1},.z{0}}` :D

Answer (score 0):

use a struct contians the similar argumensts, such as:

```
struct Shape {
  float a_radius;
  float a_rotation;
  float a_depth;
  Color a_color;
  // ...
};
```

Player::Player(Shape& shape);